# Vue3: Get updated state from Vuex into component

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vuejs3

When I update the user state in Vuex I want it to also update in the frontend instantly without a page reload. I've found some related questions, but they didn't work for me.

One thing I'm exporting the store as a function.

This is what I have right now:

```
<div v-if="user">
    test
</div>

<script>

import store from "../store";

export default {
    data() {
        return {
            user: store().getters.getUser
        }
    },

    methods: {
        // Updates the store
        login : async function() {
            await this.form.post('/api/auth/login')
                .then(response => {
                    store().dispatch('login', response.data)
                })
        }
    }

}

</script>
```

And then my vuex store would be like this:

```
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import Cookie from 'js-cookie';

const createStore = () => {
    return new Vuex.Store({
        state: {
            user: Cookie.get('jwt') ?? ''
        },

        getters: {
            getUser() {
                return state.user
            }
        },

        mutations: {
            SET_USER(state, user) {
                state.user = user
            }
        },

        actions: {
            login({commit}, user) {
                commit('SET_USER', user._id)
                Cookie.set('jwt', user._id, { expires: 7});
            }
        },
    })
}

export default createStore;
```

I've got the vue configuration correct and it's totally working except for the instantly updating frontend, it needs a page reload before the content gets updated.

I would appreciate any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changes to the store are not in scope of data properties. Change `user` from being a data property in your component to a `computed` property as recommended by the [Vuex docs](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/getters.html#property-style-access)

```
computed: {
  user () {
    return store().getters.getUser
  }
}
```

Comment: This didn't work for me even after I've made the store accessable through `this.$store`. It's only updating after a page refresh. FYI: I'm building a SPA which has no page reloads maybe that's preventing from updating?

Comment: After also changing the `store().dispatch()` function to `this.$store.dispatch()` it actually worked. I'm just wondering why `store().dispatch()` doesn't work, but `this.$store.dispatch()` does work. Anyways I'll mark your answer. Thanks for your help and reply!